# Version control for Oracle databases

Tags: oracle, deployment, version-control

I'm setting up a version control for several databases.

There are some objects like functions/procedures/packages that appear in all the databases, that is, each such object has an identical instance in each database.

In the current solution, all these objects are just (re)deployed in every database separately. But for sure there must be a better way to make the version control run more automatically by using the fact that all these databases have (copies of) the same objects.

I will be very thankful for any clue!

Answer (score 1):

There are tools like Liquibase, but those must be used carefully.
IMHO no tool can compare schemas a generate DDLs on the fly.

Liquibase has a journal table, which tracks all changes applied in the database schema. Each change is a separate xml/yaml file. Liquibase tool has a playbook (a sequence) of changes to be applied on database schema. It is idempotent and more-or-less predictable. You just need some DBA, who can predict how long a particular change can take on production data.